# JQuery call function when all AJAX requests are complete

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback

My question is a variant of the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970967/jquery-ajax-call-function-when-all-requests-are-complete)

However, there are two differences:

1. I don't know how many AJAX requests there are. For sure, there are at least 10. They run concurrently, or almost concurrently, and the number of requests changes every time.
2. The function that I want to call makes AJAX requests as well. I don't want the AJAX requests to go on forever (which is what happened when I first tried). I only want this functionality one time.

Here is my code:

```
$("#calculateButton").ajaxComplete(function() {
    $(this).unbind();
    $(this).click();
});
```

So what I *tried* to do is attach the ajaxComplete callback to the calculate button. The problem is that this executes every time an ajax request finishes. Whereas what I want is for the function to execute when *all* AJAX requests are complete.

Is there any way to do this. When I write it out, it sounds convoluted. Should I just give up and create a hacky work-around?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `.ajaxStop()` instead of your current method.

```
$("#calculateButton").ajaxStop(function() {
    $(this).unbind(); // $(this).unbind("ajaxStop") -> this is not needed as unbind will remove everything, but leaving it here as an FYI
    $(this).click();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/

**Note:** Updated code above to stop infinite loop.

Comment: As far as I understand, this will be called also when the function he wants to call stops making AJAX calls. That means this will be infinite loop (after all requests stop, callback will be called, and after requests within it will be stopped, it will be fired again, etc. etc.). This is probably the first attempt of OP to solve it - and as far as I understand it failed.

Comment: Edited my answer to prevent that.

Comment: @Tadeck: Actually the original code prevents that as `.unbind()` will remove all the handlers.

Comment: Cool. Thanks a lot. +1 for being awesome

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [deferred objects *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) introduced in jQuery 1.5.

How to set this up depends on how you make the Ajax calls, but in general it is something like:

```
$.when(callAjaxA(), callAjaxB(), callAjaxC(), ...).then(callAjaxFinal);
```

where the `callAjaxX` functions would return the promise object returned by `$.ajax`. You can also easily add new calls via [`pipe` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/).

This will execute `callAjaxFinal` once all the request issued in `callAjaxX` are finished.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably create some **local variable that will be accessible form every request**. Lets call it `ajaxCount` and assign `0` (zero) to it at the beginning.

For every request you want to count as the one that will block your function, **increase `ajaxCount` by one**. In callback executed when this particular request is finished (with error OR with success), **decrease `ajaxCount` by `1` (one)**.

Also, within every callback mentioned above, just **after you decrease `ajaxCount`, call another function**, that will **check whether `ajaxCount` equals to `0` (zero)**. If the test result is positive (meaning there is no AJAX request happening at this time), do what you wanted to do.

This is the basic idea, the implementation is rather simple. Please let me know if you have any problems regarding this.

Comment: I tried something like this, but the problem is if there are synchronous JavaScript Ajax calls you end up with ajaxCount going down to 0 only to go back up to 1 as soon as the next call is made. Let me know if you have a solution to this!