# Execute code after all ajax request are finished

Tags: javascript, ajax

This is my code:

```
function updateCharts() {
    for (var i = 0; i < charts.length; i++) {
        updateChart(charts[i]);
    }

    sortQueues();
}

function updateChart(chart) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        data: '{id: ' + chart.Id + '}',
        url: "foo/getData",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response.d);
            insertChartData(chart, parsedResponse);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            console.Log(response);
        }
    });
}
```

How can I run `sortQueues()` function after all charts are updated? Right now `sortQueues()` function is executed before `insertChartData` is finished (because ajax calls), and charts aren't sorted in html. Of course I don't want to have sync calls.

Comment: `data: '{id: ' + chart.Id + '}',` — This is not valid JSON! Don't generate JSON by mashing together strings. Do it with library functions. `data: JSON.stringify({ id: chart.Id }),`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery call function when all AJAX requests are complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795663/jquery-call-function-when-all-ajax-requests-are-complete)

Comment: Please remember to check google before posting a question. Googling your exact question title led me to the duplicate. It would have taken you less time to search than to type all that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.ajax` returns a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) so you can capture them and use them with `Promise.all`.

First return the promise:

```
function updateChart(chart) {
    return $.ajax({
```

then replace your loop with `map` so you get all the promises in an array.

```
var promises = charts.map(updateChart);
```

Then you can use the promise:

```
Promise.all(promises).then(array_of_results => {
    // all ajax requests recieved at this point
});
```

Comment: if I replace  loop with `var promises = charts.map(charts);` where `updateChart` should be launched?

Comment: @dafie — My mistake. I copy/pasted the wrong variable name. It should be `charts.map(updateChart)`