# When are all my functions complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, jquery-deferred

I have a set of async functions that issue executeSql commands to drop 2 tables, and have callbacks to create the 2 tables and populate the 2 tables.

I'd like to know when they have ALL completed.

I wouldn't mind if they executed synchronously.  In fact, I'd prefer that they ran synchronously!

Q: Would I use the jQuery pipe method to queue up these functions so that they execute in a more traditional way than issuing callbacks?

I want to do something like:

```
DropTableA();
CreateTableA();
PopulateTableA();
DropTableB();
CreateTableB();
PopulateTableB();
window.location.replace('Index.htm');
```

Comment: How are you calling these from javascript? AJAX to a server?

Comment: if you queue up the functions then you are not running them all asynchronously. If you really want to run them all asynchronously then you will need a callback to know when they finish or use a thread join techinque as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929606/join-2-threads-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at jQuery's [Deferreds and Promises](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

In short, here's an example of an async function that executes something asynchronously (setTimeout in this case). When calling the function you get back a promise.

```
var myFunc = function (value) {
    var d = $.Deferred();

    setTimeout(function () {
        d.resolve(42 * value);
    }, 1000);
    return d.promise();
};

var promise = myFunc(100);
promise.done(function (res) { console.log(res); });
```

You can use $.when to execute something when all promieses have been fulfilled, i.e.

```
$.when(p1, p2, p3).then(...)
```

If you want to execute them in order you can chain the deferreds using the [deffered's pipe](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/).

Comment: Somehow the answer always has something to do with 42, doesn't it?  Anyway, let's suppose I wanted to use pipe because that's the new hotness.  Would I do: $.pipe(DropTableA(),CreateTableA(),PopulateTableA(),DropTableB(),CreateTableB(),PopulateTableB()) ?

Comment: The pipe applies to the deferred. So you could have a function that creates the deferred, pipes to it the atomic functions that access your sql and then returns the deferred's promise.

Comment: You can try reading the docs, this is why I provided links ;)

Comment: I think I might have a handle on it after watching http://tutsplus.com/lesson/deferreds/?WT.mc_id=learnjquery

Answer (score 1):

If they are all sinchronous function (no async call inside those function) you are assured that `window.location.replace('Index.htm');` is called after all of them. If you make ajax call you could do

```
 jQuery.ajaxSetup( {async: false});
```

befare calling the first function and you are ok because all your AJAX call are now synchronous

http://jsfiddle.net/ywL63/

Comment: "I have a set of async functions" (...)

Comment: Each one of them does an executeSql

Comment: @jAndy sorry i missed that!He stated that `I wouldn't mind if they executed synchronously` so he could do as i suggested and set async to false

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti: ..if we assume that `ajax()` handlers are the only async task within those functions...

Answer (score 1):

If your functions are synchronous, just call them in the right order, as you did in your example.

Assuming instead that your function returns a `promise()` or an observable object you can simply do

```
$.when(fn1(), fn2(), ... ).done(function() {
   /* here you know that all functions have been returned, as you asked */
})
```

(note that you can use `deferred` objects not only for asynchronous tasks)

Edit: if order matters you can use this plugin:
[jQuery.whenSync() Plugin For Chaining Asynchronous Callbacks Using Deferred Objects](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2326-jQuery-whenSync-Plugin-For-Chaining-Asynchronous-Callbacks-Using-Deferred-Objects.htm)

Comment: that will not guarantee order anyway

Comment: I just answered to the question «I'd like to know when they have ALL completed.» anyway he can use as well `pipe()` to chain deferred

Comment: So I could do $.when(DropTableA(),DropTableB()).done(function() {}); and then the drop table functions would have callbacks to the create table functions and the create table functions would have callbacks to the PopulateTable functions.

Comment: maybe that was the question, but it won't stop your brain working. Not much sense it `PopulateTableA` before `DropTableA`.

Answer (score 1):

This is where jQuery deferred/promise come into play. Basically you modify your functions like this

```
function myAction1() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    $(selector).whatever(function() { dfd.resolve(); // this is one of the callbacks});
    return dfd.promise();
}
```

Then you can go and "wait" for all of the actions to complete with a construct like

```
$.when(myAction1(), myAction2(), ...).then(function() {
    // this will be executed when all the actions finished = resolved
}
```

Comment: again, this will not guarantee order of function calls. You need to invoke `.pipe()` to accomplish order.

Comment: ok the main question was to find out `when they have ALL completed`. And this is what deferred/promise will accomplish

Comment: maybe that was the question, but it won't stop your brain working. Not much sense it `PopulateTableA` before `DropTableA`.